# wait time for agent and customer in chat bot

Tags: einstein-chatbot

this query is related to chatbot in salesforce.whenever the customer is started the chat for a support may be it will take some time to connect with agent.I want to caluculate the wait time for the customer.There are two things in salesforce those "Chat transcripts" and "Chat transcript events".Is it possible to show the wait time of customer by using these.

Plese help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

a quick google search revealed this article which appears close to what you want.  Looks non-trivial..

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/files/0694S000001bJMpQAM?tab=overview

Calculate Wait Time for Bot to Agent Transfer (POC).pdf
Get a new metric on the Chat Transcript which shows the time the visitor waited for an agent to accept the chat when they were transferred by a bot.